# How do I solve dependencies problems when using Maven?

Tags: java

I recently bought a Algotrader licence and I want to make my own startegy, but when I try to install it in Eclipse I get the following errors(see the screenshot).
How can I manage to solve it ? 
[image: screenshot there]

Comment: Hi George, welcome to SO. Please take a moment and look into this to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: don't do that, please.Now the question will be seen as one with a possible answer

Comment: No it doesn´t. Again I suggest you familiarize yourself with how SO works so that others can help you more easily.